# Boolean Array in Python with custom indices

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

I am trying to create an array, lets call it a, with each element equal to True with 10 elements

I also want to be able to create a custom index so that the first element index is 2 and the last element index is 11.

Comment: You probably mean a `list` object. In which case, that (nor anything that is called an array in python) doesn't let you use a custom index. You'll have to implement that yourself.

Comment: I have posted a solution to this question for future references, but as you are *"very new to all types of programming"* I would definitely not recommend you to start with `pandas`. Maybe you can post your actual problem and explain *why* you need custom indexes in the first place so we can guide in in some direction

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a library on someone's blog that implements exactly what you're asking for, as a demonstration of how to create a `MutableSequence` class that delegates to a `list` but adds some extra functionality. Unfortunately, I don't have a link. Someone posted a link on _my_ blog post demonstrating how to create a `MutableSequence` a few years back, but then deleted it… But anyway, building it yourself could be a valuable learning exercise, but maybe too advanced for right now.

Comment: Assuming that by "array" you mean `list` or `tuple`, and that you don't need to insert or delete elements after creation, you can simulate this with a dictionary: `dictarray = {i+2: array[i] for i in range(len(array))}`. It's probably not a great idea (you end up with something that acts like a `list` but with some functionality broken, and that runs slower and doesn't print out as nice), but it might be worth playing with to see how `list`s and `dict`s work. (You might want to write that out as an explicit loop instead of a dict comprehension, though, to make sure you understand it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the array a `dict` instead.

```
a = {i: True for i in range(2, 12)}
print(a)
print(a[2], a[3], a[11], len(a))
```

This outputs:

```
{2: True, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: True, 11: True}
True True True 10
```